# model.get_weights() vs model.trainable_variables Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science

`model.get_weights()` and `model.trainable_variables` in Tensorflow seems to be returning same values in different data types. Former returns list of arrays and latter array of tensors. (If I am not mistaken)

Please, explain in which context is better to use each?
Also, I was trying to compare them but had no luck, if possible please help with a comparison code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**model.get_weights():**

- It returns the current weights of the layer, as NumPy arrays.
- This function returns a list of NumPy arrays containing both trainable and non-trainable weight values associated with this layer, which may then be used to load state into similarly parameterized layers.

**model.trainable_variables:**

- It returns all variables created when `trainable = True` in a layer. By default, it is set to true in all layers.

Hence, `model.get_weights()` and `model.trainable_variables` return the same values. Please refer to this [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/e3413f789fe1aaa2348d9f815d2bce66/67553616.ipynb) for a better understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Most likely, the difference between the two become apparent if some of the weights are frozen and and becomes non-trainable. In that case, trainable_variables and trainable_weights would be different, I am guessing.